# How to make an input dialog box in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have made an input dialog box in kivy. But I'm not sure if this is a correct format or correct code or correct way to code. I tried to display an error message itself in the popup below the button. It works while the input is empty, after input, also it's showing the error.

Can anyone help me to do it in a correct way?

```
Builder.load_string("""
<Main>:
    Button:
        text: 'Click'
        on_press: root.callit()

<design>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    cols:2
    pos: self.pos
    size: root.size
    Label:
        text: 'Enter Value'
    TextInput:
        id: val
        multiline: False
        hint_text:'Age'
        input_filter: 'int'
    Button:
        text: 'Enter'
        background_color: 255,0,0,0.9
        on_press: root.enter()
    Button:
        text: 'Cancel'
        background_color: 0,1,255,0.7
        on_press: root.cancel()
    #Label:
    #   id: er
    #   foreground_color: [1,250,100,1]
    #   text: 'Error'
""")
class design(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(design,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #cancel=ObjectProperty(None)
        self.er=Label(text='Please enter some input!')

    def enter(self):
        if self.ids.val.text=='':
            print "Enter text"
            #self.add_widget(self.er)#Label(text='Please enter some input!',width=200))
            #time.sleep(10000)
            #self.remove_widget(self.er)
            #self.ids.er.text='Please enter some input!'
            #self.ids.val.hint_text='Please enter input!'
        else:
            print self.ids.val.text
            #self.ids.val.hint_text='Please enter input!'
            self.ids.val.text=''
            self.cancel()


    def cancel(self):
        obj=OpenDialog()
        obj.call_pops(1)

class Main(BoxLayout):
    pass

    def callit(self):
        obj=OpenDialog()
        obj.call_pops(0)

class OpenDialog(Popup):
    global popup
    cont=design()
    popup=Popup(title='InputDialog',content=cont,size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 150),auto_dismiss=False)

    def call_pops(self,val):
        if val==1:
            self.close_pops()
        elif val==0:
            popup.open()

    def close_pops(self):
        popup.dismiss()


class SriPop(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SriPop().run()
```

Comment: I've made some grammatical improvements and refined the question's tagging. I have my doubts if this question is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `on_text` event so that when a number is entered the label stops showing the error. For example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<Main>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            text: 'Click'
            on_press: root.callit()

        Label:
            id: age_lab
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            text: root.str_age

<OpenDialog>:
    title: 'InputDialog'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 120
    auto_dismiss: False
    text: input.text
    lb_error: er

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos: self.pos
        size: root.size

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Label:
                text: 'Enter Value'

            TextInput:
                id: input
                multiline: False
                hint_text:'Age'
                input_filter: 'int'
                on_text: root.error = ''

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: 'Enter'
                background_color: 255,0,0,0.9
                on_press: root._enter()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                background_color: 0,1,255,0.7
                on_press: root._cancel()

        Label:
            id: er
            foreground_color: 1, 250, 100, 1
            color: 1, 0.67, 0, 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 0
            text: root.error


""")


class Main(BoxLayout):
    age = NumericProperty()
    str_age = StringProperty("None")

    def callit(self):
        obj = OpenDialog(self)
        obj.open()

    def on_age(self, *args):
        self.str_age = "Age: {}".format(self.age)


class OpenDialog(Popup):

    _age = NumericProperty()
    error = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, parent, *args):
        super(OpenDialog, self).__init__(*args)
        self.parent = parent
        self.bind(_age=self.parent.setter('age'))

    def on_error(self, inst, text):
        if text:
            self.lb_error.size_hint_y = 1
            self.size = (400, 150)
        else:
            self.lb_error.size_hint_y = None
            self.lb_error.height = 0
            self.size = (400, 120)

    def _enter(self):
        if not self.text:
            self.error = "Error: enter age"
        else:
            self._age = int(self.text)
            self.dismiss()

    def _cancel(self):
        self.dismiss()


class SriPop(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SriPop().run()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you FJSevilla!  thanks a lot.. May i ask you something? Am i good programmer? What else i should know to write programs like you? Please guide me and give some piece of advice!